# Access class attribute in event handler in js-mootools

Tags: events, properties, static, mootools, handler

I have a JS object (working with mootools) wich has stored some DOM elements and attach to them event listeners:

```
window.myObject = {
    init: function(el1ID, el2ID){
        this.myElement1 = document.getElement(el1ID); 
        this.myElement2 = document.getElement(el2ID);

        this.myElement1.addEvents({
            'click' : function(){
                 myObject.myElement2.innerHTML("foo");
             }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, this works only if i had only one object `myObject` in the page. I have to create another object for another structure `el1ID`-`el2ID` and I would like to make this object a class and instantiate an object for every structure, in order to keep every event handling independent from the others. My problem is: how can I access in the event handler the attributes of the `myObject` object?

```
'click' : function(){
    myElement2.innerHTML("foo")
 }
```

won't work and

```
'click' : function(){
    this.myElement2.innerHTML("foo")
 }
```

would search for `myElement2` as a property of `myElement1` (aka the event raiser). What can I do in stead of accessing staticly the properties of my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click event callbacks are Element-centric and will trigger with the Element as the execution context, i.e. `this === myObject.myElement1` in this:

```
    this.myElement1.addEvents({
        'click' : function(){
             myObject.myElement2.innerHTML("foo");
         }
    });
```

there is no `Element.prototype.innerHTML()` method in MooTools, btw. It's `Element.prototype.set` and is used as `el.set('html', someString);`. Used to be `.setHTML()` in 1.1x

To be able to access your object, you have several patterns.

```
    this.myElement1.addEvents({
        'click' : function(e){
             this.set('html', 'foo');
         }
    });
```

To access the parent object, you can either rebind or save a reference in a variable instead:

```
    this.myElement1.addEvents({
        'click' : function(e){
             // this === myObject
             this.myElement2.set('html', 'foo');
             // getting to original
             e.target === this.myElement1; // from event object, like currentTarget
         }.bind(this) // <-- binding to outer object instead
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

A better (arguably, I prefer it a lot of the time to binding due to unbinding event handlers) pattern is to save the reference:

```
init: function(){
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.myElement1.addEvents({
        'click' : function(e){
             // self is orig. this === self.myElement1;
             self.myElement2.set('html', 'foo');
         }
    });
}
```

That's about it.